# Why text append outside svg element d3js?

Tags: d3.js

I try to add text on svg element like this

```
var chart = d3.select('.chart')
                .attr('width', 200)
                .attr('height', 200);


var left_axis = chart.select('.left_axis')               
    .data(left_axis_data)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 20})
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

my example: http://jsfiddle.net/zkcq86v2/1/ Why text append outside svg element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `select` to `selectAll` to make sure the attributes are applied to all elements

```
var left_axis_data = [
    {
        name : 'a',
        nmb : '1',
        state : '0'
    },
    {
        name : 'b',
        nmb : '2',
        state : '0'
    },
    {
        name : 'c',
        nmb : '3',
        state : '0'
    }
];

var chart = d3.select('.chart')
                .attr('width', 200)
                .attr('height', 200);


var left_axis = chart.selectAll('.left_axis')               
    .data(left_axis_data)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 20;})
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```